# How to use strpos() to check a variable's path?

Tags: php, strpos

I have a home page that shows some uploaded images.

I take it from the database and I use `strpos()` to check the URL due to directory problems, and it works fine:

```
if(strpos($row['cImage'],"http://") === FALSE){
    echo "<img src='serintercement/".$row['cImage']."' style='width: 107px; height:102px;' />";    
}else{
    echo "<img src='".$row['cImage']."' style='width: 107px; height:102px;' />";    
}
```

I need to use the same logic in a page that shows the clicked image, but it has a variable for it and I'm struggling to fix this since it's a different way to write:

```
<img src='<?php echo $resultData->cImage; ?>'/>
```

I can't fix the directory problem. How can I use `strpos()` similarly for this second code?

Comment: Do you want to use `$resultData->cImage`, like wise you were doing for `$row['cImage']`?

Comment: yes @SahilGulati. i want this image coming from this variable to have it's path checked, so i can correct it if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
if(strpos($resultData->cImage,"http://") === FALSE){
    echo "<img src='serintercement/".$resultData->cImage."' style='width: 107px; height:102px;' />";    
}else{
    echo "<img src='".$resultData->cImage."' style='width: 107px; height:102px;' />";    
}
```

Better option is you can define a function like this and call it

```
checkImage($row['cImage']);//to be called in your first page
checkImage($resultData->cImage);//to be called in your second page
function checkImage($image)
{
    if(strpos($image,"http://") === FALSE){
        echo "<img src='serintercement/".$image."' style='width: 107px; height:102px;' />";    
    }else{
        echo "<img src='".$image."' style='width: 107px; height:102px;' />";    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to check the path similarly - as long as the property of the object is set and a string, [strpos()](http://php.net/strpos) can be used.

```
if(strpos($resultData->cImage,"http://") === FALSE){
    echo "<img src='serintercement/".$resultData->cImage."' />";    
}else{
    echo "<img src='".$resultData->cImage."' />";    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If these `cImage` strings are coming from your database, you could just correct them in the query call.

For example, if you are using MySQL, you could prepare the data using `LOCATE()` AND `CONCAT()` like this:

```
SELECT
    IF(LOCATE('http',`cImage`)!=1,CONCAT('serintercement/',`cImage`),`cImage`) `new_cImage`
FROM ...
```

Moving the conditional process to your query, will make your "displaying" code read more smoothly because all of the preparations are completed ahead of time.

---

Outside of that, you can make your code more DRY by not repeating the html parts that come before and after the image variable...

This is an echo with an inline condition (not everyone likes this style):

```
echo "<img src=\"",(strpos($resultData->cImage,"http")===0?'':'serintercement/'),"{$resultData->cImage}\" style=\"width:107px;height:102px;\" />\n";
```

This is a separated conditional:

```
echo "<img src=\"";
    if(strpos($resultData->cImage,"http")!==0){
        echo 'serintercement/'
    }
echo "{$resultData->cImage}\" style=\"width:107px;height:102px;\" />\n";
```

This is a function call if you have to do this multiple times in the same script:

```
function fixPath($img){
    if(strpos($img,"http")===0){
        return $img;
    }
    return "serintercement/$img";
}
echo "<img src=\"",fixPath($resultData->cImage),"\" style=\"width:107px;height:102px;\" />\n";
```

---

Notice that I am only checking for `http` and that I am very accurately checking that it comes from the first position in the string.  Across all these alternatives, the point I am making is DRYness (which is a typical pursuit of all programmers).  How you chose to implement it comes down to your personal preference.